# Homomorphism between multiplicative group of integers modulo n

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, modular-arithmetic

Just looking for anybody to check the following:

We have got a homomorphism $f: (\mathbb{Z}/42\mathbb{Z})^{*} \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}/21\mathbb{Z})^{*}$, given by $f(a\text{ mod} 42)= a \text{ mod} 21$.

a.) What is the kernel of $f$ ?

b.) Is $f$ bijective?

My answer would be:

$$(\mathbb{Z}/42\mathbb{Z})^{*}=  \{ \pm 1, \pm5, \pm 11, \pm13,\pm 17, \pm 19\}$$
$$(\mathbb{Z}/21\mathbb{Z})^{*} = \{1,2,4,5,8,10,11,13,16,17,19,20 \}$$

a.) $\ker(f) = \{x \in(\mathbb{Z}/42\mathbb{Z})^{*} ; x \equiv 1 \text{ mod} 21 \} \subset \{ ..., -20, 1, 21, 43, ...\}$

So I conclude  $\ker f = \{1\}$

b.) I would say yes, because for all the positive values of $(\mathbb{Z}/42\mathbb{Z})^{*}$ you can just call them $\text{mod}21$. The same is true for the negative values. So I can connect all elements from  $(\mathbb{Z}/42\mathbb{Z})^{*}$  uniquely to a specific element in $(\mathbb{Z}/21\mathbb{Z})^{*}$.

For b (if it is correct), can I use other strategies?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you mean *homomorphism* ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homomorphism)), not *homeomorphism* ([see here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeomorphism)).

Comment: hehe tnx you are right

Comment: Any mapping between finite sets of the same size is surjective if it is injective, and therefore bijective. What can you say about $f$ if it has trivial kernel (i.e., its kernel is only the identity)?

Comment: Do you mean that the groups are isomorphic, since ker(f)=1, which is a normal subgroup, hence isomorphism implies a bijection?

Comment: @MSKfdaswplwq, no: the kernel is always a normal subgroup. See if you can prove that any mapping with trivial kernel is injective (hence, the hint in my previous comment). Then you get surjectivity for free and can conclude it's a bijection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct for both (a) and (b).

As an alternative for (a) use that $21\mid a-1 \iff 42\mid a-1$. This follows from the fact that $a\in(\mathbb{Z}/42\mathbb{Z})^{*}\Rightarrow a$ is odd.

And for (b) note that it follows from (a) since $f$ is one to one (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_%28algebra%29#Group_homomorphisms)) and both sets $(\mathbb{Z}/42\mathbb{Z})^{*} \text{ and } (\mathbb{Z}/21\mathbb{Z})^{*}$ have 12 elements.